# Jquery and ajax, when not success response

Tags: jquery

I have code like this:

```
 $(".delete").click(function() {    
    var commentContainer = $(this).parent();
    var id = $(this).attr("id");            
    var string = 'id='+ id ;
    $.ajax({   
        url: "<?php echo site_url('admin/delete_admin') ?>",
        type: "POST",
        data: string,
        cache: false,
           error: function(){
            $(this).parent().append('You can not delete admin. Please contact main admin .');
        },
        success: function(){
            commentContainer.slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});               
        }         
    });
    return false;
});
```

and PHP:

```
function delete_admin()
{        
    $q = $this->admin_model->get_admin();
    if($q->privilege == 'main_admin')
        {
      $this->admin_model->delete_admin( $_POST['id']);         
        } 
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
}//end of delete_admin
```

How to send message that user can't do delete? Function is working like it is success every time (container is sliding).

Comment: `error: function(){` is when an actual error in the response occurs. Ie. Response error or TCP error as an example. Not when your logic returns `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response data is sent to the `success` callback function, so you can pick it up and check the value.

If you return the string "ok" for success:

```
success: function(data) {
  if (data == "ok") {
    commentContainer.slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});               
  } else {
    $(this).parent().append('You can not delete admin. Please contact main admin.');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the header to any of the error codes. Use php's `header` function to set header to 400.

Using codeigniter, you can use this kind of call to convey error message;

```
$this->output->set_header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request");
```

In your PHP code do,

```
function delete_admin()
{        
  $q = $this->admin_model->get_admin();
  if($q->privilege == 'main_admin')
    {
      $this->admin_model->delete_admin( $_POST['id']);         
    } 
    else 
    {
        $this->output->set_header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I think that I need something like this in another request :D. Thank you.